# How do I test a helper method in my application_helper file in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My application_helper.rb file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def option_text(option_id)
    Option.find(option_id).title
  end
end
```

Where do I test this method at?  Rails generates helper test files when I create a scaffold, but where do I put a test for this method, since it's in the Application Helper?  I have tried placing the test in one of the view helper test files generated with the scaffold, but it can't find the method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a folder under test/unit called 'helpers', then create your helper test files like this:

```
# application_helper_test.rb
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../test_helper'
require 'action_view/test_case'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test 'option_text' do
    assert true
  end
end
```

There are some other helpful tips on testing helpers here:
http://technicalpickles.com/posts/helper-testing-using-actionview-testcase/